# Neo4j - MATCH Query Optimization

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize the Neo4j Cypher query which is taking quite long time on 1 Million nodes.

My query is:

```
MATCH (org:Organization{id:'ec92'})-[S:EMPLOYED_BY]-(person:Person) RETURN person
```

In this query, I am trying to find out the people who are working in a particular organization.

I have UNIQUE Constraint on the Organization:id property.

```
Constraints
  ON (organization:Organization) ASSERT organization.id IS UNIQUE
```

**Time taking = 83001 ms i.e., 83 secs**

What all I can do to optimize this query as my data is supposed to grow exponentially.

And, look at the Query planner
[image]

Comment: You can add the direction on the relationship, and remove unused variables (ie. org & S). But I don't thinks this will decrease a lot the response time. Can you give us a PROFILE of this query ?

Comment: What is the result of this query : `MATCH (org:Organization{id:'ec92'})  RETURN size((org)--())` ?

Comment: size((org)--()) -->>
238572

Comment: @logisima Edited the question profiler image

Comment: You are building a result of 45K rows ... Where does this time comes from ? The browser ?

Comment: Yes. from the Browser.

Comment: You should know that this time is not the query time, but the time used by the browser to handle the query. So here you asked it to display 45k row, and of course it's slow. Can you execute the query  from the `cypher-shell` to see the difference ?